# Howto get html popup inside svg at correct position (using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, tooltip

I have a simplr svg-graph and I'm trying to create a simple
tooltip-popup for this graph, but I'm unable to find out how to set the position
of the tooltip properly.

I have a .css where my popup-div is absolute:

```
#popup {
    position: relative
```

When creating nodes in the svg I hook a listener like:

```
    p.setAttributeNS(null,"onmousemove","parent.drawPopup(evt)");
```

Now to my problem, in the drawPopup callack, I cannot figure out how
to set the coordinates correctly, I've tried something like the following
in the drawPopu function:

```
pop = document.getElementById("popup"); 
pop.innerHTML = popupText;
pop.style.visibility='visible';
pop.style.left=evt.pageX + 'px';
```

but the pageX seem to be relative to the svg.graph, so I need to offset it somehow?

How does one usually do with problems like this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to position the tooltip absolutely, your CSS rule states *relative*, and use the mouse x,y coordinates to place it on top of the graph since the tooltip is triggered by the mouse pointer anyways.

This link to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) will have some helpful info, scroll down the page or search for **mouse position** and you'll find some tips on accurately calculating mouse x,y coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Raphael.

http://raphaeljs.com/

Excellent vector javascript library.

Comment: You could have at least explained how he could do it with Raphael, instead of just promoting it.

Comment: Agreed. Actually, I just found this post because I'm looking for a way to do popups with Raphael....and there's no easy way to do so!